# Cleaner resource URLs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I'm looking for some help on making my URL's more appealing to users in my Rails app. 
The app is on 3.2.11 and I'm running ruby 1.9.2p320

I currently have two models that I think perhaps could be cleaner in the URL representation, Company and Consultant.

They both have unique fields, Company has :name and Consultant has :username.
Company has_many :consultants
Consultant belongs_to :company

I'm using friendly_id so both resources have these unique ID's in the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/company/:name
```

and

```
http://localhost:3000/consultants/:username
```

My routes looks like this:

```
resources :company, :path => '/company'

resources :consultants, :path => '/consultants'
```

Now I'm wondering if there would be any neat way of making it possible to have the urls look like this for company:

```
http://localhost:3000/:name
```

and like this for consultants:

```
http://localhost:3000/:name/:username
```

I would greatly appreciate any help on this matter if it is possible, thanks!
I apologize right away if I've left out any crucial info that's needed.

/Rasmus

Answer (score 0):

you can change the :path to whatever you want, for example:

```
resources :company, :path => '/company'
```

to

```
resources :company, :path => ''
```

wich will delete the /company/ from your url

Here a gem which you also can use, but it has lots of functions so I guess its to heavy for your needs:
[friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

This is a great guide about routing and namespacing: [Rails routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: That works, but how do I handle my company_index_path? now that gets me the root.

Comment: I'm using the friendly_id gem already that is how I handle the companies and consultants by name and not ID.

Comment: you can use match "new_path_you_want_to" => "companies#index" or but i guess thats not what you want change the root_to to something different. Hope it helps you

Comment: I haven't had much luck yet, I tried using :path => '' for company and match "new_company_index_path" => 'company#index' but it seems to break other links....

Comment: I see 2 possibilities for you, but maybe there are more and better ones. You could root_to to a different url not localhost:3000/ or you use a namespace like localhost:3000/your_name_space/:name/:username I think name-spacing is the cleaner way.